# How to paginate a grid with selected columns

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

In the Agile Toolkit Tutorial (Jobeet), I setup the quick data model (Page 3) and it looks nice with the CRUD test page. I tried to change a line of code in the test.php file. The problem is when I added the paginator, line of code, the data in the grid disappeared. Is this a limitation to the paginator class? Is there a quick way to get this custom grid paginated? Thanks.

Original Code displays method not defined error when adding addPaginator as shown below:

```
    $this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Category');
    //$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Job');
    $jobCRUD=$this->add('CRUD');
    $jobCRUD->setModel('Job');
    $jobCRUD->addPaginator(3);  //This line causes an method not defined error
```

Modified code using setSource doesn't display an error but displays an empty grid:

```
class page_test extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        //$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Category'); //Not needed for my example
        $grid=$this->add('Grid'); 
        //$grid->setModel('Job'); //Removed this to show custom columns
        $grid->addColumn('id');
        $grid->addColumn('type');
        $grid->addColumn('position');
        $grid->setSource('job');
        $grid->addPaginator(3);  //Added this to paginate the results (doesn't work & removes data)
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
    $this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Category');
    //$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Job');
    $jobCRUD=$this->add('CRUD');
    $jobCRUD->setModel('Job');
    $jobCRUD->grid->addPaginator(3); // This fixed the paginator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobeet is for Agile Toolkit 4.1 and uses "setSource" which is obsolete.

I think if you replace setSource with setModel it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks that's what I started off with. The CRUD works nice but then I wanted 2 things done. (1) Eliminating extra columns and just displaying id,type & position fields and also I wanted (2) paginate to function and unless I'm typing the syntax wrong, it doesn't work.

Comment: OK I created unique columns by adding a new Model with only the fields I wanted to display from the database.  I'm still stuck on how to get the addPaginator class to work for the CRUD example

Comment: OK I got it and it was simpler than I thought. I just needed $jobCRUD->grid->addPaginator(3)  :) Thanks